# SQL Server reports 'Invalid column name', but the column is present and the query works through management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've hit a bit of an impasse. I have a query that is generated by some `C#` code. The query works fine in `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` when run against the same database.

However when my code tries to run the same query I get the same error about an invalid column and an exception is thrown. All queries that reference this column are failing.

The column in question was recently added to the database. It is a date column called `Incident_Begin_Time_ts` .

An example that fails is:

```
select * from PerfDiag 
where Incident_Begin_Time_ts > '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Other queries like `Select MAX(Incident_Being_Time_ts);` also fail when run in code because it thinks the column is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a problem with case maybe? Perhaps Management Studio doesn't care about case, while other ways of accessing the database are more strict.

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with the same database in your code as the one in Management Studio?

Comment: Are you sure that the column name you created in C# and the column name you try to query are exactly the same? In your question, you're writing twice 'Incident _ **Begin** _ Time_ts' and once 'Incident _ **Being** _ Time_ts'.

Comment: @Oliver: case-sensitivity is not per-connection. It's as a database/sql server option.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I suspect that you have two tables with the same name. One is owned by the schema 'dbo' (`dbo.PerfDiag`), and the other is owned by the default schema of the account used to connect to SQL Server (something like `userid.PerfDiag`).

When you have an unqualified reference to a schema object (such as a table) — one not qualified by schema name — the object reference must be resolved. Name resolution occurs by searching in the following sequence for an object of the appropriate type (table) with the specified name. The name resolves to the first match:

- Under the default schema of the user.
- Under the schema 'dbo'.

The unqualified reference is bound to the first match in the above sequence.

As a general recommended practice, one should **always** qualify references to schema objects, for performance reasons:

- An unqualified reference may invalidate a cached execution plan for the stored procedure or query, since the schema to which the reference was bound may change depending on the credentials executing the stored procedure or query. This results in recompilation of the query/stored procedure, a performance hit. Recompilations cause compile locks to be taken out, blocking others from accessing the needed resource(s).
- Name resolution slows down query execution as two probes must be made to resolve to the likely version of the object (that owned by 'dbo'). This is the usual case. The only time a single probe will resolve the name is if the current user owns an object of the specified name and type.

[Edited to further note]

The other possibilities are (in no particular order):

- You aren't connected to the database you think you are.
- You aren't connected to the SQL Server instance you think you are.

Double check your connect strings and ensure that they explicitly specify the SQL Server instance name and the database name.

Comment: +1 I use sql profiler to track these types of issues down. Any time you deal with dynamic sql from other applications, capture the query with a trace, copy & paste it into a new query window, click execute to find out what's wrong. This will also validate that you are connecting to the correct instance and db as suggested above.

Comment: ... slightly off topic but if you are using profiler to reproduce performance issues, **remember to include all the set options**, particularly ARITHABORT to truly duplicate the query (and it's cached plan)

Comment: First try with Ctrl + Shift + R, to reload cache. Worst case you only waste a few seconds.

Answer (score 351):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and see...

In SQL Server Management Studio, [Ctrl+Shift+R refreshes the local cache.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

Comment: Why do you think doing that would be helpful?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, Ctrl+Shift+R refreshes the Intellisense cache. This did stop Management Studio from complaining that the columns I'd added are invalid, but I think that was a red-herring (I still have a problem, like the original poster, when accessing these new columns from code).

Comment: Seems every time I Add-Migration, then Update Database, I have to do this.  Otherwise I get that it's an invalid column name in MS SQL Server. Works! So much thanks.

Comment: Looks like you might have to do this every time you create a table or anything of that sort.

Comment: Apparently my IntelliSense cache did not update itself after creating then dropping and recreating a column, reconnecting to the database did not help, so Ctrl + Shift + R saved the day. Thanks!

Comment: You won't get a C# query error if your intellisense cache is out of date. At worst you won't see a recently removed column but this does not apply in the OP

Comment: This above is normally my go-to-solution when weird things occur. In this case however it did not solve the problem. Restarting SQL Studio did the trick though.

Comment: I knew about the local cache refresh, but I really hadn't connected it to this error message. This gave me the needed clue to get rid of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In my case I restart Microsoft SQL Sever Management Studio and this works well for me.

Comment: This is simply what was causing my problem. Tried everything else and nothing solved but this.

Comment: It's always worth trying the easiest thing. Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 12):

If you are running this inside a transaction and a SQL statement before this drops/alters the table you can also get this message.

Comment: +1. I altered a table by adding anew column and was getting this error in the next statement referrencing the new column. I overcame this by executing the statements till the table alteration in one go and then the rest in another. Not the greatest of solutions but got me unblocked. :)

Answer (score 5):

I eventually shut-down and restarted Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio; and that fixed it for me.  But at other times, just starting a new query window was enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using variables with the same name as your column, it could be that you forgot the '@' variable marker. In an INSERT statement it will be detected as a column.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the exact same problem. I renamed some aliased columns in a temporary table which is further used by another part of the same code. For some reason, this was not captured by SQL Server Management Studio and it complained about invalid column names.

What I simply did is create a new query, copy paste the SQL code from the old query to this new query and run it again. This seemed to refresh the environment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to get the value from wrong ResultSet when querying multiple SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems the problem was a weird caching problem. The solutions above didn't work.

If your code was working fine and you added a column to one of your tables and it gives the 'invalid column name' error, and the solutions above doesn't work, try this: First run only the section of code for creating that modified table and then run the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Including this answer because this was the top result for "invalid column name sql" on google and I didn't see this answer here. In my case, I was getting Invalid Column Name, Id1 because I had used the wrong id in my .HasForeignKey statement in my Entity Framework C# code. Once I changed it to match the .HasOne() object's id, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error when running a scalar function using a table value, but the Select statement in my scalar function RETURN clause was missing the "FROM table" portion. :facepalms:

Answer (score 0):

Also happens when you forget to change the ConnectionString and ask a table that has no idea about the changes you're making locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a View, but the exact same SQL code worked perfectly as a query. In fact SSMS actually threw up a couple of other problems with the View, that it did not have with the query. I tried refreshing, closing the connection to the server and going back in, and renaming columns - nothing worked. Instead I created the query as a stored procedure, and connected Excel to that rather than the View, and this solved the problem.