# How to fix invalid 'Invalid column name' after adding a column in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, outsystems

I have added a column in to my existing table. But, it is giving me an error.

I don't know what is going on.

I have a very simple table

```
    Invalid column name 'COMPANYDESIGNATION'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at OutSystems.HubEdition.DatabaseProvider.SqlServer.ExecutionService.ExecutionService.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at #gCb.#BCb.ExecuteReader(String description, Boolean isApplication, Boolean transformParameters, Boolean skipLog)
   at OutSystems.Internal.Db.DatabaseAccessProvider`1.ExecuteQuery[T](Command cmd, GenericRecordList`1 rl, String description, Boolean transformParameters, Boolean skipLog)
   at OutSystems.Internal.Db.DatabaseAccessProvider`1.ExecuteQuery[T](Command cmd, GenericRecordList`1 rl, String description)
```

Why is it giving me an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some more details like code. It's easy for finding solution.

Comment: Hi @jainvikram444, using the OutSystems platform I have an existing table with a very simple structure: Table Name: Contacts


Table Name: Contacts

Columns:
Id
FirstName
LastName

and I just added a new column: CompanyDesignation

and it's giving me an error.

Comment: Maybe this cound be the reason? Due to schema.
[report 'invalid column name'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260487/sql-server-reports-invalid-column-name-but-the-column-is-present-and-the-quer)

Comment: What does your table look like? What query are you firing?

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger, I have an existing table with a very simple structure: Table Name: Contacts Table Name: Contacts Columns: Id FirstName LastName and I just added a new column: CompanyDesignation...I didn't do any query yet..Just added a column and hit on published and the platform is giving me error feedback.

Comment: Thanks @PavelVanecek will check it out.

Comment: Do you have only 1 eSpace? If you have more, did you refresh all references?

Comment: Hi @FilipeMartins, I have just refreshed all dependencies. But, still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.

The problem was I disregarded the error of my 'Address' table.

It has a problem with its foreign key.

Every time there's an error in the compilation, I just republish.

And the application gets publish successfully.

But, this isn't true. I believe the cycle of the entire compilation is interrupted with this error.

So, now every time I will see an error in the compilation -- I should fix (lesson learned)..

I updated my 'Address' table which has the error. Now, I can successfully add attributes to my 'Contact' table.

I hope this will shed some light to someone who's having the same problem as I had.

*Happy coding everyone!*

:)