# Fix casting issue between stored procedure in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I am writing a spring boot application where I incorporate a stored procedure in my code. I have an entity class that has 8 columns and I have a stored procedure that takes a parameter and passes back 3 of the columns from that entity class. However, when I make a call to the stored procedure it throws a `java.land.ClassCastException`. I tried fixing this by adding the `resultClasses` to the stored procedure, but when I run that code, it fails because it says I am using all 8 column names. So I am not sure if it is because of a stored procedure issue or because I am implementing it wrong in my Java code. When I say that I mean I don't think I am casting it right.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value = {
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "procedure-edit",
                procedureName = "GetQueryConf",
                resultClasses = AppSelectorTier.class), 

        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name= "procedure-getTierType",
        procedureName= "GetTierTypeByObj",
        //resultClasses = AppSelectorTier.class,
        parameters= {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode= ParameterMode.IN, name= "taddm_obj", type= String.class),                
        }),



})

public class AppSelectorTier implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tiername")
    private String tiername;

    @Column(name = "system")
    private String system;

    @Column(name = "mqllisting1")
    private String mqllisting1;

    @Column(name = "mqllisting2")
    private String mqllisting2;

    @Column(name = "tagname_one")
    private String tagname_one;

    @Column(name = "tagname_two")
    private String tagname_two;

    @Column(name = "parseinstruction")
    private String parseinstruction;

    @Column(name = "taddmobj")
    private String taddmobj;

    // Constructor
    public AppSelectorTier(String tiername, String system, String mqllisting1, String mqllisting2, String tagname_one,
            String tagname_two, String parseinstruction, String taddmobj) {
        super();
        this.tiername = tiername;
        this.system = system;
        this.mqllisting1 = mqllisting1;
        this.mqllisting2 = mqllisting2;
        this.tagname_one = tagname_one;
        this.tagname_two = tagname_two;
        this.parseinstruction = parseinstruction;
        this.taddmobj = taddmobj;
    }


    public AppSelectorTier(String tiername, String system,String tagname_two) {
        super();
        this.tiername = tiername;
        this.system = system;
        this.tagname_two = tagname_two;
    }






    // Default Constructor
    public AppSelectorTier() {

    }

    // Getters

    public String getTiername() {
        return tiername;
    }

    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    public String getMqllisting1() {
        return mqllisting1;
    }

    public String getMqllisting2() {
        return mqllisting2;
    }

    public String getTagname_one() {
        return tagname_one;
    }

    public String getTagname_two() {
        return tagname_two;
    }

    public String getParseinstruction() {
        return parseinstruction;
    }

    public String getTaddmobj() {
        return taddmobj;
    }

    // Setters

    public void setTiername(String tiername) {
        this.tiername = tiername;
    }

    public void setSystem(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }

    public void setMqllisting1(String mqllisting1) {
        this.mqllisting1 = mqllisting1;
    }

    public void setMqllisting2(String mqllisting2) {
        this.mqllisting2 = mqllisting2;
    }

    public void setTagname_one(String tagname_one) {
        this.tagname_one = tagname_one;
    }

    public void setTagname_two(String tagname_two) {
        this.tagname_two = tagname_two;
    }

    public void setParseinstruction(String parseinstruction) {
        this.parseinstruction = parseinstruction;
    }

    public void setTaddmobj(String taddmobj) {
        this.taddmobj = taddmobj;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AppSelectorTier [tiername=" + tiername + ", system=" + system + ", mqllisting1=" + mqllisting1
                + ", mqllisting2=" + mqllisting2 + ", tagname_one=" + tagname_one + ", tagname_two=" + tagname_two
                + ", parseinstruction=" + parseinstruction + ", taddmobj=" + taddmobj + "]";
    }



}
```

`procedureName= "GetTierTypeByObj"`
This procedure returns only tiername,system, and tagname_two

**Service Layer:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<AppSelectorTier> getTierTypeFromObj(String parameter) {
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("procedure-getTierType").setParameter("taddm_obj", parameter);
            return storedProcedure.getResultList(); 
        }
```

**Java Implementation:**

```
            if (joinQueryService.getTierTypeFromObj("WebService").size() != 0) {
                AppSelectorTier selectorObj = joinQueryService.getTierTypeFromObj("WebService").get(0);
                System.out.println("Tiername: " + selectorObj.getTiername());
                System.out.println("System: " + selectorObj.getSystem());
                System.out.println("Tagname two: " + selectorObj.getTagname_two());

                current.getQuery();
                current.setTier(selectorObj.getTiername());
            } else {
                temp = "";
                current.getQuery();
                current.setTier("");

            }
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.UPS.entity.AppSelectorTier
```

Comment: //resultClasses = AppSelectorTier.class

Answer (score -1):

You may have missed this:

```
//resultClasses = AppSelectorTier.class
```

Try to uncomment.
If you do not specify a class, the Object type will be returned.
Set:

```
resultClasses = {AppSelectorTier.class},
```

Comment: I undid the comment  and now it says that, ```mqllisting1``` is not valid column.

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260487/sql-server-reports-invalid-column-name-but-the-column-is-present-and-the-quer/7260645