# Force a stored procedure to fail when a column not exits?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Sometimes it happens that I have some errors in stored procedure body, e.g.

```
select invalidColumn from validTable
```

When I try to create/alter stored procedure, it works and I can see the error only when I try to execute the stored procedure.

Is it possible to force schema check when I create or alter?

Comment: *"When i try to create/alter stored procedure, it works"* are you sure? The definition of the objects are checked at the time to SP is compiled: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=284eeea469c3e62551c6d7800966720a). If, however, you change the definition *after* the SP is created, that's a different story: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25897a5eb0d276c83fd39ade91699cda). *Perhaps* that's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @Larnu - here's an example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fad4a473a664a915462420170bf6d8c (reference to the temp table means that the compilation of the statement is deferred)

Comment: Please take a look at 1st and 3rd solution given in this link which might give you a hint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260487/sql-server-reports-invalid-column-name-but-the-column-is-present-and-the-quer

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith . The OP doesn't say that have temporary tables, in fact they simply say that just have `select invalidColumn from validTable` (though I doubt it's that simple). An [mre] will really help us help them here.

Comment: There used to be a Connect issue asking for a `schemabinding` option for stored procedures. Of course, Connect got binned and I can't find the equivalent on MS's current feedback system. Needless to say, it's been asked for for more than a decade and MS seem to continue to ignore the request.

Comment: This shouldn't really be a problem anyway as you should be using something like tsqlt so that the proc is actually executed and verified correct before deployment anyway

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `SCHEMA_BINDING` *is* available on Stored Procedures, but they need to be Natively Compiled so you can't just add `SCHEMA_BINDING` to a "normal" SP. Not sure if that's what you're referencing though: [Creating Natively Compiled Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/creating-natively-compiled-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu - that is the option, yes, but it was feedback to MS back in the ~2008 timeframe I think that they add the option to stored procedures (and natively compiled wasn't a thing yet at that time). It's an option that has long existed for functions and views and ensures that referenced objects exist (and don't get removed) which would seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I don't disagree, having `SCHEMA_BINDING` on non-natively compiled Procedures would be nice as well, @Damien_The_Unbeliever , just wanted to clarify that it *is* possible, just not as easily as on other object types.